# how to update uid

Tags: wpf, msbuild

I am learning about how to localize a project.

I added the UICulture to .csproj file and also in the assembly file:

```
[assembly: NeutralResourcesLanguage("en-US", UltimateResourceFallbackLocation.Satellite)]
```

but now in the book I am following, I am being instructed to update the elements with the uid.

I don't know where to do the above

I haveto invoke the msbuild ( which I am not sure from where ) and need to use

```
msbuild /t:updateuid ProjectName.csproj.
```

I know its really a very simple question.

Comment: I have found the Msbuild by looking into the microsoft.net version and also changing the path and using the msbuild command was able to update.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have found the Msbuild by looking into the microsoft.net version and also changing the path and using the msbuild command was able to update.

The book i am following is WPF unleashed